# Re-using result of function call in dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I use `dplyr::do` with `glm` to fit a model by group to example data. I want to add columns with the upper and lower limits of the confidence interval: how can I avoid making the call to `confint` twice? In general, is there a way to assign generic output to a new column using `dplyr::mutate`?

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c("a", "b"), each=10),
  y = c(rpois(10, 0.5), rpois(10, 2.2)))

sdf <- df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  do(fit=glm(y ~ 1, poisson, data=.))

mutate(sdf,
  est=coef(fit),
  cil=confint(fit)[1],
  ciu=confint(fit)[2])
```

In short, I want this to work:

```
mutate(sdf, ci=confint(fit)) %>%
  mutate(cil=ci[1], ciu=ci[2])
```

If I use `do` again, I lose the fitted model and `x`.

**Solution**

What I actually used (learned from the accepted answer):

```
sdf <- df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  do({
    fit <- glm(y ~ 1, poisson, data=.)
    ci <- confint(fit)
    data.frame(
      est=coef(fit),
      cil=ci[1],
      ciu=ci[2])
  })
```

Comment: Have you seen [broom](https://github.com/tidyverse/broom)? That might help you get those model outputs as columns in a dataframe

Comment: @Ben 's suggestion can be implemented as simply as `do(tidy(glm(y ~ 1, poisson, data = .)))` in place of your `do` call.

Comment: I'd also look into using `purrr` for this sort of work.  You can use `do` but the `map` functions in `purrr` provide a lot of flexibility.

Comment: @JakeKaupp I don't know `purrr` at all, can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all of the above comments are nice newer packages to help with your problem (I highly recommend `purrr`), but if you want to stick with `do` you can reformat it like this so you only are calling `confint` once per group:

```
sdf <- df %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    do({fit <- glm(y ~ 1, poisson, data=.);
        data.frame(confint(fit), coef(fit))})
```

the output requires some work to get into a plotable format:

```
sdf %>% mutate(ci = rep(c("low", "high"), legnth.out = nrow(.))) %>% spread(ci, confint.fit.)
```

Comment: Sorry for the superfluous edit (a copy-paste mistake made me think a ';' was necessary ... wrong language).

Comment: no worries, you were right and that's why I accepted it, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

As asked in the comments, here's an approach using `dplyr`, `purrr`,`tidyr` and `broom`.

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

sdf <- df %>%
  nest(y) %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~glm(y ~ 1, poisson, data = .))) %>% 
  unnest(map(model, tidy))

Source: local data frame [2 x 8]

       x            data        model        term   estimate std.error statistic      p.value
  (fctr)           (chr)        (chr)       (chr)      (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)        (dbl)
1      a <tbl_df [10,1]> <S3:glm, lm> (Intercept) -0.5108256 0.4082458 -1.251270 2.108361e-01
2      b <tbl_df [10,1]> <S3:glm, lm> (Intercept)  1.0296194 0.1889795  5.448311 5.085025e-08
```

I would read more about `purrr`, `tidyr` and `broom` via google, and the package vignettes.  There is also a lot of good information on the [RStudio Blog about tidyverse packages](https://blog.rstudio.org/category/tidyverse/).